# Adding a dynamic view - Layout gravity problem

Tags: android

I am adding a dynamic layout view which looks like this. 
[image: Sample View]

I am appending this view on button click. Here is the code for this view on button click

```
public void addDynamicView() {
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    LinearLayout lHori = new LinearLayout(this);
    lHori.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    //lHori.setWeightSum(3);
    lHori.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    LinearLayout lVertical = new LinearLayout(this);
    lVertical.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    //lVertical.setWeightSum(2);
    lVertical.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));


    Button button = new Button(this);
    button.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)));
    button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    button.setText("button");

    TextView txtEmpName = new TextView(this);
    txtEmpName.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 18);

    txtEmpName.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    txtEmpName.setText("txt1");


    TextView txtEmpDropTime = new TextView(this);
    txtEmpDropTime.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    txtEmpDropTime.setText("txt2");

    lVertical.addView(txtEmpName);

    lVertical.addView(txtEmpDropTime);


    lHori.addView(lVertical);
    lHori.addView(button);

    relativeLayout.addView(lHori);
    linear.addView(relativeLayout);
}
```

The problem is I want all the buttons to be placed below the **click** button.
But I get output like this

[image]

How can I place all Button with text Button below the **Click** button?

Comment: align parent right

Comment: RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)button.getLayoutParams();
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);

button.setLayoutParams(params); //causes layout update

Answer (score 0):

You can create a LinearLayout lButton:

```
LinearLayout lButton = new LinearLayout(this);
lButton.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

then set its gravity as Gravity.END

```
lButton.setGravity(Gravity.END)
```

and add the button into it

```
lButton.addView(button);
lHori.addView(lVertical);
lHori.addView(lButton);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you two do with xml than it's so simple just make a layout which you want after click on click button after that set visibility gone for all layout accept click button next in Java on button click you can call visibility view to make that layout ...
Hope so it will works for you..